# Powershell script that imports from CSV, checks AD account status, then exports to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am writing a Powershell script to take a CSV file of Active Directory accounts, validate each account, and write the validation status back to a separate CSV file. I need assistance in writing the CSV; I've looked at the Export-Csv cmdlet but I'm a little confused how it would work when I am already importing a CSV. Here is my code so far:

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\drives.csv | Foreach-Object{

$user = ([ADSISEARCHER]"(samaccountname=$($_.SamAccountName))").FindOne()

if($user)
{
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
        IsDisabled = $user.GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeGet('AccountDisabled')
    }
}
else
{
        Write-Warning "Can't find user '$($_.SamAccountName)'"
}
```

}

Any thoughts on how to export both the account name (which is being imported from one CSV) and the account status (which my current script provides)?

Comment: Rather than store the disabled property to a variable (IsDisabled), why not just write the value out, just as you did with the warning? You could then either pipe the output to a file or expressly write it to a CSV...

Comment: What's the purpose of the script?

Comment: Don't overthink it - export-csv with a path to the file and the -NoTypeInformation flag looks like a good starting point. You might mod the script to accumulate your entire result into a string, and pipe the single string to the CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility - untested, but it is intended to illustrate the export-csv. All standard caveats apply :)

```
$resultList = @()
Import-Csv C:\Users\drives.csv -header("SamAccountName") | Foreach-Object{

   $user = ([adsisearcher]"(samAccountName=$($_.SamAccountName))").FindOne()

   $resultList += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
           SamAccountName = $_.SamAccountName
           IsDisabled = if ($user) { 
                            $user.GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeGet('AccountDisabled') 
                        } else {
                            "User not found."
                        }
       }

}

$resultList | export-csv -Path c:\users\driveresult.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I ran this and get an error saying "Missing = operator after key in hash literal." This is at line 7 where the first $resultList appears

Comment: @HeathHackett Think I fixed it :)

Comment: Ok so this no longer gives me error messages but does not work properly. It went through the first two records in the imported csv and returned true which is good but then it hit the third record where the account does not exist and it gives me a repeating message "Can't find user (SamAccountName). Additionally the export CSV now has data but it is nonsense. Thank you for all your help so far

Comment: @HeathHackett Okay I think *this* time I actually thought a bit more about it and actually made it work :) I modified the logic a bit to create the New-Object each time, and then conditionally set the IsDisabled attribute to reflect either its disabled status or whether the account was found. See if this works for you.

Comment: So I ran this and now in powershell it presents my data nicely and then creates an export CSV. But when I open the newly created CSV it is empty (no data whatsoever)

Comment: I am a dummy!!! Failed to assign the new objects to the resultList array. ***NOW*** it should work @HeathHackett

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121968/discussion-between-heath-hackett-and-david-w).

Answer (score 0):

```
$exportCsv = @()

Import-Csv C:\Users\drives.csv | Foreach-Object{
    $user = ([ADSISEARCHER]"(samaccountname=$($_.SamAccountName))").FindOne()

    if($user)
    {
        $exportCsv += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                        SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
                        IsDisabled = $user.GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeGet('AccountDisabled')
                      }
    }
    else
    {
            Write-Warning "Can't find user '$($_.SamAccountName)'"
    }
}

$exportCsv | Export-Csv -Path $myOtherCsvFilePath
```

Here you add a Powershell array of PSObjects to another CSV file

Comment: So in the last line do I need to put the path of the CSV I'm importing or just the path to where I want to export?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your Code a bit.

```
  Import-Csv C:\Users\drives.csv | Foreach-Object{

  $user = ([ADSISEARCHER]"(samaccountname=$($_.SamAccountName))").FindOne()

  if($user)
  {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
      SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
      IsDisabled = $user.GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeGet('AccountDisabled')
    }
  }
  else
  {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
      SamAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
      IsDisabled = 'not found'
    }
  }
} | export-csv myNew.csv -Append -NotypeInformation
```

Now you wont lose object info by piping.

Comment: I tried this and am getting a 'Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the export-csv value of this type "system.string" to type "system.management.automation.ScriptBlock" and then it also gives me an error with my first line of code where I am importing.

Comment: Still gives the same error. Do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: Yep, forgot to set a `|` -.-